# Производится ли оптимизация вызовов функций при умножении на ноль?

Tags: java

Пусть, есть выражение:

```
int result = a1*function1() + a2*function2();
```

Где `a1,2` - это коэффициенты 0 или 1.
А `function1,2` - это довольно тяжеловесные по вычислительной сложности функции.

То если `a1`, например, равен нулю, будет ли вычисляться `function1()`? Или сразу примет значение 0?

Comment: К слову, при умножении на 0 не всегда может получиться ноль... )

Comment: Например, результат выражения `0 * Float.NaN` будет не равен нулю )

Comment: Ну, или как-то так: `int result = (a1 == 0 ? 0 : a1 * funct1()) + (a2 == 0 ? 0 : a2 * funct2());` **Пояснение:** тернарным оператором проверяем на 0 две переменные.

Comment: А довольно изящно, чёрт побери! Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> То если a1, например, равен нулю, будет ли вычисляться function1()? Или сразу примет значение 0?

Будет. Укороченная оценка (Short-circuit evaluation) работает только для двух логических (булевых) операторов `&&`  и `||`.

Answer (score 2):

Простейший способ узнать это, не прибегая к помощи SO - отладочный вывод в помощь:

```
@Test
public void ttt() {
    int a1 = 0;
    int a2 = 1;

    int result = a1 * function1() + a2 * function2();

    System.out.println(result);
}

private int function1() {
    int result = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        result *= new Random().nextInt() * new Random().nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("func1 calculated");

    return result;
}

private int function2() {
    int result = -100500;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        result += new Random().nextInt() + new Random().nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("func2 calculated");

    return result;
}
```

> ```
> func1 calculated
> func2 calculated
> -1045391715
> ```

**Ответ:** да, `function1` будет вычисляться.

Comment: Можно короче вроде?) `private int function1(){
    System.out.println("func1 calculated");
    return 1;
}`

Comment: @Ksenia, разумеется можно, я вставил туда псевдовычисления, дабы продемонстрировать что компилятор случайно ничего не соптимизирует :) Вообще такие вопросы как у автора возникают от того, что сейчас очень много говорят мол компиляторы слишком умные. Они умные да, но порой люди переоценивают их возможности.

Comment: Компилятор не имеет права выбросить вызов метода с побочными эффектами, этот код не доказывает ничего

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это понятно. Однако, может быть есть способ как-то избежать сложных вычислений, зная то, что результат заведомо нуль? Таким образом отыграть немного скорости.

Comment: @Cyryl Передавайте в метод первый аргумент выражения и проверяйте, если он равен нулю, то сразу возвращайте нуль, без расчетов.